# Use of variables in recursion

Tags: algorithm, sorting, recursion, data-structures, linked-list

I have written below code to reverse the first K nodes of linked list, It had some issue resolved in [Reversing first K nodes of Linked List,Why recursion executing twice for last iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36668348/why-recursion-executing-twice-for-last-iteration), Now it working expected but why it leads to loop in linked list when i  try to use variable "k" instead of "presentCounter" in "if" condition,what is the reason? and how to avoid it?

```
 /*
 * Condition K <= Length of linked list.
 *  node = null
 *  nextNode headNode of the linked list
 */

public void reverseNode(Node node, Node nextNode, int k) {

    int presentCounter = k;
    if (k > 1) {
        k = k - 1;
        this.reverseNode(nextNode, nextNode.next, k);
    }

    if (presentCounter == 1) {
        this.kNode = nextNode.next; // Saving K's Next Node
        this.headNode = nextNode; // Setting K node as head node
    }
    if (node == null) {
        nextNode.next = this.kNode;
    } else

        nextNode.next = node;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `presentCounter` is also used later to check for the last element to swap with `if (presenceCount == 1)`.
If you naively get rid of `k` and use `presentCounter` instead

```
if (presentCounter > 1) {
    presentCounter = presentCounter - 1;
    this.reverseNode(nextNode, nextNode.next, presentCounter);
}
```

since now `presentCounter` has been decremented, the check for the last element to swap triggers one item before.

For example in the list `[a b c d]` when requested to swap the first three elements, the check should be true for `c` so that `this.kNode` is `d`.
If instead is true one step before, i.e. for `b`, then `this.kNode` is `c` (and the head is set to `b`).
When linking the elements in reverse order (*c b a*), the old head<sup>1</sup> is linked to `this.kNode`, so we end up with two different result:

- **Corret** (`this.kNode` is *d*)
  *c b a d*
- **Incorrect** (`this.kNode` is *c*)
  *b a c b a c ...*

The second one is a loop.
You can easily get rid of `k` though

```
if (presentCounter > 1)
    this.reverseNode(nextNode, nextNode.next, presentCounter-1);
```

---

In order to better understand what is going on, here is a picture.

You have to understand that there are two phases: the traversing phase
(when the recursion call is made) and the building phase (when the recursion
calls have returned).
So each invocation is pictured twice.

*pc stands for presentCounter*

[image: traversing phase]

[image: building phase]

---

<sup>1</sup> the first element, the one saved in `nextNode` when `node` is *null*, ie the first invocation of the function.

Answer (score 0):

When k is 2 it enters the first condition (k > 1)

then it will decrement k and recurse

but then *after the recursion finishes* it will continue to the next line.

k=k-1 gives 1, so "if (k == 1)" will perform the actions inside that second conditional as well on the same pass.

By saving k into presentCounter before you subtract one from it, then checking presentCounter == 1, you avoid this extra task being done twice (once inside the recursion call because k == 1 now, and again when the recursion finishes).